# Al iniciar sesión con google no me genera el token OAuth

Tags: javascript, oauth2, google-oauth

Al crear el inicio de sesión con google no me genera el access token para poder posteriormente con ese token acceder a la api de google drive.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
function decodeJwtResponse(token) {
        let base64Url = token.split('.')[1]
        let base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
        let jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(atob(base64).split('').map(function(c) {
            return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
        }).join(''));
        return JSON.parse(jsonPayload)
    }

    let responsePayload;
    function handleCredentialResponse(response) {

        responsePayload = decodeJwtResponse(response.credential);

        console.log("ID: " + responsePayload.sub);
        console.log('Full Name: ' + responsePayload.name);
        console.log('Given Name: ' + responsePayload.given_name);
        console.log('Family Name: ' + responsePayload.family_name);
        console.log("Image URL: " + responsePayload.picture);
        console.log("Email: " + responsePayload.email);
    }
```

**Da como respuesta:**

ID: Aquí me genera 21 números

Full Name: Mi nombre completo

Given Name: Mi primer nombre

Family Name: mi primer apellido

Image URL: Foto de la cuenta

Email: Correo

pero no el token para acceder a la api de google drive o cualquier otra api que me pida OAuth.

Comment: ¿Qué petición te ofreció esos datos? En esa petición debiste usar un testigo (token) de aplicación o un testigo de sesión. ¿Cuál de los dos usaste? Es obvio que esta no es la manera de obtener el testigo de un flujo de autenticación OAuth. ¿De dónde sacaste este código? ¿Estás siguiendo algún manual o tutorial? Ponnos un poco en contexto.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Estoy haciendo login con la api de google para javascript lo cual genera una credencial y de ahí se sacan los datos. he intentando usar el response.credential sin descifrar como token pero no funciona. solo obtengo datos de la cuenta y yo necesito un token para usarlo en las apis de google.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código de la página de retrollamada del flujo OAuth? En ese código es donde obtienes el testigo que necesitas.